# What should be in ISO 9001 quality manual?

Tags: quality, quality-management

As far as I understand, then ISO 9001 Quality Manual should contain the following information:

- statement about quality policy (vision, committment)
- statement about quality objectives (for each line of business, product)
- list of all the procedures (the content of procedures should be in appendices, procedures themselves further specify how records, required by Standard, should be collected, kept and used)

That's all, only 3 short parts. Is that all? Then why all the available sample Quality Manuals tries to reproduce standard and does not goes into specifics of companies.

Comment: What sample Quality Manuals are you looking at? If any are available to the general public, can you link to them?

Answer (score 2):

Every Quality Manual will be specific to the company that has implemented the ISO 9001 standard, and no two will be completely identical even when looking at companies in the same industry. If you are looking online for sample manuals to use as a starting point, you won't be able to find a sample that includes any company specifics unless you are referencing an actual ISO manual from an organization that has shared this online. Typically, when companies are starting the process of moving to ISO they will engage the assistance of certification experts who works with management in creating the quality manual for the organization based on the outline of the original standard.